# DDay iCal FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, icalendar, dday

This is my code:

```
public Schedule(string vCalendar)
{
    IICalendarCollection allEvents = iCalendar.LoadFromStream(new StringReader(vCalendar));
}
```

The vCalendar string object is a .ical/.ics file that I read in.
Why does this throw a FileNotFoundException?

Isn't this suppose to work with a string coded in an ical/ics format.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? Your code works for me. A calendar string is correctly loaded and I can browse the contents in debug. I fear something else is causing your file not found exception.

Answer (score 0):

dday.ical isn't supported in WP8.1 (or WinRT), so the DLL can't be loaded.